# Every ajax/ jQuery.post() result returns prefixed with a variable 'f'

Tags: php, jquery, post

Every jQuery.post()  call returns the string prefixed with an unwanted letter 'f'.

```
function show_leads_zone_list(sel_value) {
$.post('<?php  echo base_url();?>lead_management/show_all_zone', {operation_id:sel_value}, function(data) {
    alert(data);
    $("#leads_zone_div").html(data);
    }); 
}
```

function in Controller:

```
function show_all_zone()
{

    echo "test";
}
```

on calling this function show_leads_zone_list() , it alerts "ftest".
This happens with every ajax function.

Comment: may be you some where in your page echo or print f

Comment: try to find the f in your page

Comment: there was this letter in my model

Comment: if it unwanted means just remove it

Answer (score 1):

You must have printed some variable which result the letter 'f' or may be printed the letter 'f' directly. If you are getting this letter in AJAX, make sure whether the same letter displaying on all pages or not. If so, view the source code and that will help you to find the location of this letter. Share your page link, if you have, to check the issue.

Comment: That  was right . I had this f at the top of my model page.